# How can I represent simple percentage calculation in mathematical notation?

Tags: notation

I want to show my calculation/logic using mathematical notation but have no experience of this other than seeing them in research papers I have read.

In my example I have three values 90, 11, 57 and I want to show using mathematical notation how those values can be expressed as a percentage and subsequently choose the greatest number, so...

```
90 + 11 + 57 = 158

90 / 158 = 0.57
11 / 158 = 0.07
57 / 158 = 0.36

Answer = 0.57
```

However, in my notation I would like to demonstrate that the total number of values in the set can vary.

I have read up on Sigma/Summation and can see how I can use that to sum up the values however I get somewhat confused when I start to consider the variable number of values in the set and how that could be represented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum percentage of $n$ values $x_i,\,1\le i\le n$ is $\frac{\max_ix_i}{\sum_jx_j}\times100\%$.

Comment: could you just explain the relevance of 1 ≤ i ≤ n?

Comment: @AndrewHB It tells us over which values $i$ runs to maximize $x_i$. We also sum over the same values of $j$ in the denominator.

Comment: Ah OK so it defines the range 1 - n, thank you for your help!